# Вызов функции при сворачивании приложения

Tags: swift, spritekit

Доброго времени суток!

Пожалуйста, помогите новичку разобраться, ибо самостоятельно разобратьcz не смог и материал немного сложен для меня.

В моем проекте есть несколько сцен  (SKScene), нужно чтобы при сворачивании приложения вызывалась определенная функция. Как я понял, надо сцены для начала связать с AppDelegate. После чего уже производить необходимые настройки.

Не могли бы ли Вы объяснить как с этим работать.

Привести пример хотя бы для одной сцены. Все остальное я сделаю самостоятельно для других сцен.

Comment: есть нотификейшн `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`, подпишитесь на него и делайте, что вам надо. Пример надо показать?

Comment: Пример, да, пожалуйста. Если Вам не трудно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подписаться на нотификейшн (в классе, который должен знать что приложение уходит на бэкграунд)

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(fade), name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

Создать метод, который будет выполняться при уходе на бэкграунд

```
func fade() {
    print("NOOOO!!!!!!")
}
```

не забыть убрать обсервер

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Создайте пустой проект и замените ViewController таким вот кодом чтоб протестировать

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(fade), name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func fade() {
        print("NOOOO!!!!!!")
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Я конечно прошу прощения, но боюсь, что в этой теме я полный профан. Не могли бы ли Вы объяснить подробнее, пожалуйста.
Вот к примеру в сцене я прописываю строку:
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(fade), name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
Что нужно дописать в селекторе? или в name?
Для чего делать удаление обсервера?

Comment: добавил в ответ